# Как создать SOAP запрос из xsd схемы

Tags: python, xml, soap, xsd

Я работаю с запросами в SOAP-сервис, и часть запросов предоставляется в xsd-схемах. Я не знаю, как работать с этими схемами, и пытаюсь по схемам воссоздать вид xml-запроса, чтобы отправлять этот xml сервису.

Схема такая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:ecat="http://intellex.ru/Etran/ASUASU/Categories">
    <xs:import namespace="http://intellex.ru/Etran/ASUASU/Categories" schemaLocation="EtranCategories.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="EtranCommonMessages.xsd"/>

    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Сообщения информационного обмена АС Этран - внешнее АСУ. 
            Информация о наличии/отсутствии заготовок накладных на порожние собственные вагоны поданные, но не убранные с пути необщего пользования.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:element name="invoiceFiledCars">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Запрос справки о наличии/отсутствии заготовок накладных на порожние собственные вагоны поданные, но не убранные с пути необщего пользования. 
                Поиск данных осуществляется за период 60 дней. В ответ АС Этран возвращает invoiceFiledCarsReply
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="invoiceFiledCarsReply">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Список заготовок накладных на порожние собственные вагоны поданные, но не убранные с пути необщего пользования. 
                В ответе передается список порожних вагонов с накладными на порожняк, если они есть (только в состояниях "Приемосдатчиком принято" и "Согласование уведомления"). Ответ на запрос invoiceFiledCars. </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="SimpleAnswer">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="invoiceFiledCar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        </xs:element>          
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="invoiceFiledCar">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> Накладная на поданный собственный порожний вагон</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>   
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Document" type="SimpleDocument" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Электронный документ на поданный собственный порожний вагон.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="FiledCarDate" type="ecat:DateTimeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Дата подачи на путь необщего пользования</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Car" type="TCar" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Поданный собственный порожний вагон</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Station" type="TStation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Станция подачи</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ToStation" type="TStation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Станция назначения</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Я подумал, что данные `invoiceFiledCar` будут полезны для воссоздания запроса. Здесь указаны сложные типы данных, определенные в подключаемых схемах:

`type="ecat:DateTimeType"`

```
<xs:simpleType name="DateTimeType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Дата в формате DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="19"/>
            <xs:pattern value="(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0[13578]|1[02])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\.(0[13456789]|1[012])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\.02\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\.02\.((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))) (([0,1][0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

`TCar`

```
 <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Вагон</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="carNumber" type="ecat:TCarNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

`TCarNumber`

```
<xs:simpleType name="TCarNumber">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Номер вагона</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{4,20}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

`TStation`

```
<xs:complexType name="TStation">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Станция</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="StationId" type="ecat:IDShortPosType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Идентификатор станции</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation> 
      </xs:element>
      <xs:group ref="StationCodeGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="StationName" type="ecat:String40Type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Наименование станции</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation> 
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

По этим данным я написал такой запрос:

```
<invoiceFiledCars version="1.0">
    <FiledCarDate value="01.07.2018"/>
    <Car>
        <carNumber value="1"/>
    </Car>
    <Station value="1"/>
</invoiceFiledCars>
```

Не уверен, что все сделал правильно. Как сформировать этот запрос? Пишу на питоне.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли атрибуты version и value? В схеме их нет!

Comment: А вообще, ваша задача не имеет решения. Для формирования SOAP-клиента нужна wsdl-схема, а не только xsd.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, wsdl-схема есть.